# Slow/low file transfer rates on 802.11n wi-fi network

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, file-transfer

I have an Xtreamer media player and a Windows 7 laptop connected wirelessly to a DLINK DIR-615 router. When I try to transfer a large file from the media player to my laptop the tranfer rates are ~1MBps. Unusable.

- Both hosts are connected in 802.11n mode with signal strength in the 50-60% range.
- Router Config: Wifi router configure for 802.11n only. The card on my laptop doesn't have a similar option so it is set to the default b/g/n mode.
- Router Config: Using WPA2 for security got me to ~1.2 - 1.5MBps.
- Router Config: Used a different Channel that the default of 6.

Internet searches reveal that there a lot of other tormented souls but no definite answers.

How can I increase the transfer rates over the LAN to at least 5-6 MBps?

Comment: Does the issue pertain only to large files? What's your throughput on non-large files?

Answer (score 2):

You might have other appliances (or those of neighbors) that are interfering with your wireless connection.

- Try rebooting your router and modem. I had the exact same problem for a week and this fixed it.
- Try moving the Xtremer a few feet and see if there is any improvement
- The DSL Reports tweaker program might be able to diagnose your problem http://www.dslreports.com/tweaks
- This tool lets you perform the tweaks http://www.dslreports.com/drtcp

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. If it's possible, connect one of the devices to the router via a Cat 5 ethernet cable. It more than doubled my speed and you'll get even faster if you connect both to the router via ethernet. Short of that you can also try to enable Frame Bursting, and set the preamble type to "Short" using the advanced settings on your router. Both of those should slightly increase the throughput of your router.